# Disable Statement Execution API in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

There is a new feature "Statement Execution API" in Azure Databricks. As part of some security policies in our organization, we need to disable this feature. How can we achieve it

Answer (score 2):

Statement Execution API is simply a way for users to run queries on data to which they already have access. There are a few ways to restrict users from using this feature.

1. Manage the user's access through admin settings, or use unity catalog for a better access control.
2. Every API call needs a Personal Access Token (PAT) for authorization. You can manage the list of users that can create a PAT, or entirely disable PAT under `Admin settings` > `Workspace settings` > `Access control`.
3. Create an API wrapper and drop any requests that utilize Statement Execution API. Generate a single PAT and use it for your wrapper. Provide this wrapper's endpoint to any user that needs to use Databricks API for their jobs.

Note that disabling PAT entirely could break jobs that use Databricks API in their code.